# Radiators not bleeding no air or water. Boiler pressure is good. What could be wrong? Plz help Thanks

Tags: heating

Plumbing

My radiator won't bleed no air or water . Boiler pressure is good what could be wrong. Plz help

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What is the problem you're trying to solve, and where are you located? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Sounds like you have a compound problem. a) your radiator isn't making heat, and b) your bleed valve is plugged solid.  I would say it sounds like the radiator is vapor-locked, and  fixing b) would allow you to bleed it and fix that.

Comment: Are there any isolation valves which have been left closed?